# linq query returning string with carriage return

Tags: linq, newline

I have a ProductDescriptionEn as a string from DB and can't get the carriage return to work. It can be a big description and the output is on 1 line.

I did read about Environment.NewLine but can't have it working and I tried this who doesn't help neither:

```
query = (from pc in _context.ProductDescribeFulls
         where pc.ProductId == Id
         select new ProductDetail
                         {
                             ProductDescriptionEn = pc.ProductDescriptionEn.Replace("vbCrLf", "\r\n")
                         }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Any Idea?

Text shows as :

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged...

Should be:

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged...

Comment: how does it now work? are you trying to display this? if so where?

Comment: I display it in a mvc 5 view with a model as string

Comment: I din't get what is the problem? Replace is not working or something else?

Comment: Replace doesn't make any changes. The all text displays on one line without respecting the carriage return for new lines.

Comment: One of two things can happen: 1 "vbCrLf" does not exist or does not match exactly.  2 you are putting this content in an html content for which a carriage return is meaningless... You might need to put it in a <p> tag and replace "vbCrLf" with a line break like <br />